# SimpleDateFormat parseexception when parsing time

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I have converted some dates to string and stored them in my database using

```
      DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

they look like this: "12-09-2012 02:33:00" when they come out as strings

I am then trying to retrieve them using

```
      DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

this gives me a parseexception saying that it's and unparsable date this is the exception message:

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12-09-2012 02:33:00" (at offset 2)

Here is some code to give a better understanding of what I am doing:

```
    String start="";
    String slut="";
    DateFormat formatterday = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

            start=formatterday.format(formatterday.parse(a.startTime));
            slut=formatterday.format(formatterday.parse(a.endTime));
```

I have tried sepparating my statements so that I parse first and then format and the error seems to appear during parse.

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: Ah sorry I should have mentioned. starttime and endtime are strings previously converted from dates

Comment: @Ken Can you *System.out.println* them (the two strings)?

Comment: Yes I was able to print them on my device(android) before I tried to remove the date and keep the time. - maybe I could split the string instead of converting I really only need a visual representation (I just did a system.out.println(); and I was able to get the string)

Comment: Why store dates as string when SQL has a `DATETIME` date type? No formatting, no parsing, just dates.

Comment: Android uses sqlite database which only has string, real, blob, integer so dates are stored as strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple date format accepts specific pattern, and your string value "12-09-2012 02:33:00", clearly doesn't follow given pattern "hh:mm:ss". In order to convert original date string to date object you need to use original pattern.

Simple example:

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

String originalDateValue = "12-09-2012 02:33:00";
Date originalDate = formatter1.parse( originalDateValue );

String shortDateValue = formatter2.format( originalDate );
Date shortDate = formatter2.parse( shortDateValue );

System.out.println( originalDateValue );
System.out.println( originalDate );

System.out.println( shortDateValue );
System.out.println( shortDate );
```

This will print out:

```
12-09-2012 02:33:00
Wed Sep 12 02:33:00 CEST 2012
02:33:00
Thu Jan 01 02:33:00 CET 1970
```

Notice that shortDate has value from beginning of era -> 1.1.1970.

Comment: Thank you very much this explains the sollution very well. the clarifying factor was what you said about the pattern

Answer (score 2):

@Ken your date format of the a.startTime variable should have the "hh:mm:ss" format.

if your a.startTime value is something like 02:33:00 then your code should work.

So check your a.startTime value and use correct date format.